# how to plot vertical offset in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple scatter plot as below.  After plotting the data and the fit, I would like to show the errors (with direction) for each data point.  I am struggling to do it in matplotlib

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

house_dic={'sqf':[700,950,1100, 1400, 2000],'price': [780, 800, 950, 1500, 1900]}

house=pd.DataFrame(house_dic)
plt.scatter(house['sqf'],house['price'])
plt.xlabel('Square Feet')
plt.ylabel('Price $K')

w=1
y_fit=house['sqf']*w
plt.plot(house['sqf'], y_fit)
```

the final graph should look like this (I manually drew the arrows in keynote) 
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`plt.arrow()`](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/arrow_simple_demo.html).

The first four arguments are: starting x (`sqf`), starting y (`y_fit`), change in x (here, 0, since we want vertical lines), and change in y (which I've computed as a fraction of the residual distance).  The `arrow_dim` values change the size of the arrow head.

```
resid = house['price'] - y_fit
shrink = -.2
arrow_dim = (20, 20)

for i in range(len(house)):
    plt.arrow(house.loc[i, 'sqf'], y_fit[i], 0, resid[i] + resid[i]*shrink , 
              head_width=arrow_dim[0], head_length=arrow_dim[1], fc='r', ec='r')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: @andrew_reece- thank you very much! this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(32)
exp = np.arange(1,11)
salary = np.random.randint(20000,100000,10)
salary = salary[0]*0.1*exp + salary
salary = np.sort(salary)
x = exp.reshape(-1,1) # To change 1 Dimesion to 2 Dimension
y = salary
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x,y)
y_pred = model.predict(x)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y_pred,c='r')
for i in range(len(x)):
  plt.plot([x[i],x[i]],[y[i],y_pred[i]],c='k')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvQR3.png)
Try this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)
of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, 
and probably result in more up-votes. 
Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, 
not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.